# Construir un formulario que ocupe una fila completa de un una tabla

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Quiero construir un formulario que ocupe la fila completa de una tabla, lo quiero hacer para meter diferentes campos y controles en cada una de las celdas pero no funciona, los métodos helper construyen el cierre del formulario enseguida de su apertura.

Mi código en la vista es el siguiente

```
<% content_for :title, t('.title') %>
<table class="table table-hover">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>
      <%= hp_human_name_for(:training_day, :current_workout_station) %>
    </th>
    <th>
      <%= hp_human_name_for(:training_day, :alt_workout_station) %>
    </th>
    <th>
      <%= hp_human_name_for(:person, :photo) %>
    </th>
    <th>
      <%= hp_human_name_for(:person, :member) %>
    </th>
    <th>
      <%= hp_human_name_for(:person, :code) %>
    </th>
    <th>
      <%= hp_human_name_for(:attendance, :check_in) %>
    </th>
    <th>
      <%= hp_human_name_for(:training_day, :progress) %>
    </th>
    <th>
      <%= hp_human_name_for(:training_day, :current_exercise) %>
    </th>
    <th>
      <%= hp_human_name_for(:training_day, :next_exercise) %>
    </th>
    <th>
      <%= t('.action') %>
    </th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <% @training_days.each do |training_day| %>
    <tr>
      <%= form_for(training_day, url: start_admin_training_day_path(training_day)) do |f| %>
      <td>
        <% if training_day.current_workout_station %>
          <%= "##{training_day.current_workout_station.number}" %>
        <% else %>
          <%= f.collection_select(
              :current_workout_station_id,
              @workout_stations,
              :id,
              :number,
              { include_blank: false},
              class: 'form-control') %>
        <% end %>
      </td>
      <td>
        <% if training_day.current_workout_station %>
          <%= hp_field_content(training_day.alt_workout_station) %>
        <% else %>
          <%= f.check_box(:alt_workout_station) %>
        <% end %>
      </td>
      <td class="routine-person-photo">
        <% if training_day.attendance.person.photo.attached? %>
          <%= image_tag url_for(training_day.attendance.person.photo) %>
        <% else %>
          <%= image_tag url_for('person_photo_default.png') %>
        <% end %>
      </td>
      <td>
        <%= hp_field_content(training_day.attendance.person.full_name) %>
      </td>
      <td>
        <%= hp_field_content(training_day.attendance.person.code) %>
      </td>
      <td>
        <%= hp_field_content(training_day.attendance.check_in) %>
      </td>
      <td>
        <%= hp_field_content(training_day.progress) %>
      </td>
      <td>
        <%= hp_field_content(training_day.current_exercise&.name) %>
      </td>
      <td>
        <%= hp_field_content(training_day.next_exercise&.name) %>
      </td>
      <td>
        <% unless training_day.current_workout_station %>
          <%= f.submit(t('.start'), class: 'btn btn-primary') %>
        <% end %>
      </td>
    <% end %>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Me construye esta linea html para el formulario y abajo las celdas con los campos y controles, me está construyendo la etiqueta de cierre enseguida de su apertura

```
<form class="edit_training_day" id="edit_training_day_4" action="/admin/training_day/4/start" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post"></form>
```

Comment: Más info por favor.¿a que métodos helper te refieres? ¿cuál es el código de esos helper? ¿cuál es el html generado?

Comment: En este caso me refiero al metodo form_for que lo estoy cerrando casi hasta el final del codigo antes de la etiqueta </tr>

Comment: Esta es la linea html que me construye                                                     
 <form class="edit_training_day" id="edit_training_day_4" action="/admin/training_day/4/start" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post"></form>

Comment: Dentro de la etiqueta form no me contruye las celdas ni los campos